# borderTopLeftRadius and borderBottom on react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

i have a button component in react-native like this:

```
<View style={{ ... }}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: 5, borderBottomWidth: 2, borderBottomColor: 'red', ...}}
  >
    <Text>
      Button
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

and the result is this:

[image]

but i want this:

[image]

Why there is a shade in the left bottom? Is it normal?